# Modal to push segue with Objective-C in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying make an app.It starting in profileViewController and if user is not login I have a segue and it is modal.I'm showing LoginViewController.I have a signup button in loginViewController.If User tap that button I have a segue and its need the pushing SignUpViewController. but I'm taking error `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <ProfileViewController:`

```
Test[1875:468590] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController:

    [LoginViewController signUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController signUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

what should I do
Thanks

Comment: By just providing that error message without providing  small relevant snippets of code or describing what you're doing with the relevant view controllers, all we can really do is look at the error messages and say "Don't do that!".   Did you create the segue id in the Storyboard for the VC, and are you doing the peformSegue... call *from* the VC where you set up the segue ID, *while* the VC is active and  it's view is visible?  And if you're using any custom transition animators (I doubt it because that's pretty advanced), don't, until you get a basic transition working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should present UINavigationController modally. RootViewController of this navigation controller will be LoginViewController. And then just push SignUpViewController.